# How can I create a bootable CD-ROM/USB Drive? (With NTFS + USB Drive support)

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

My motherboard got fried and I was forced to get a new hardware set (MB+CPU+RAM) so in most likelyhood I'll need to reinstall my `Windows 7`.

I usually follow procedure and put the OS on the primary partition and my data on a logical partition - so I can format the primary without concern - but this time I made a mistakte and left some crucial items on the primary partition.

I want to create a bootable CD-ROM/USB Drive which can read NTFS so I can access this data. If booting via a CD-ROM, I would prefer being able to connect a disk-on-key/My Passport to the computer and be able to access it to transfer the data to it.

How can I do it? (free 3rd party applications are most welcome)

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple as data recovery from an NTFS partition, I'd go with just a linux LiveCD (or LiveUSB). It'd be a fully functional OS so NTFS support and USB Mass Storage support shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: your bog standard ubuntu varient might work quite well for this . In this particular case you might also need to use the force mount option of NTFS-3G - http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g . If you need a liveusb, take a look at unetbootin

Answer (score 0):

As Tarek pointed out, the easiest way is to use **Linux LiveCD / LiveUSB** to read and backup your data.

**Knoppix** is the oldest Live distribution and it can read (and even write on) NTFS without major issues. More info [here](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/knoppix51-en.html).

Btw, Ubuntu can also [read NTFS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=362554) and this distribution now exists in LiveCD / LiveUSB too.

To my mind, the easiest way to install a Linux on a pen drive is to use this small Windows utility [LiveUSB Install](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/liveusb-install-live-usb-creator/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) to recover files from computers before, along with [uNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a Live USB stick. The benefit of using a Live USB is that, depending on the size of the stick, you could save the files from your computer to the USB Stick.